# I got stuck on ModelState.IsValid in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I get stuck on the `ModelState.IsValid`. I try to solve them from the other example, but it not worked. Could you guy help on me please?

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("DepartmentId,DepartmentName,LocationId")] Department department)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["LocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Location>(), "LocationId", "LocationId", department.LocationId);

        return View(department);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the `Department` model class?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi ,
Please use this code it will work.**

```html
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("DepartmentId,DepartmentName,LocationId")] Department department)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions that occur during saving changes to the database
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occurred while saving the department.");
    }

    ViewData["LocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Location>(), "LocationId", "LocationId", department.LocationId);
    return View(department);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replied but it's not work. I saw this when I debugged 
{[Location, SubKey={Location}, Key=Location, ValidationState=Invalid]}
And I add "?" to my model already but it's still not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The debug output you mentioned, [Location, SubKey={Location}, Key=Location, ValidationState=Invalid], indicates that the validation for the "Location" property has failed.

To address this issue, you can try the following steps:

Make sure that the "Location" property in the Department class has the necessary validation attributes (e.g., Required, StringLength, etc.) to ensure the input value is valid
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
public string Location { get; set; }

Comment: If you have already added the ? operator to the model binding expression ([Bind("DepartmentId, DepartmentName, LocationId")] Department department?), this should allow the department parameter to be nullable, which can handle cases where the model binding fails. However, make sure you have also updated the action method signature to accept nullable types, like this
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("DepartmentId, DepartmentName, LocationId")] Department? department)